# Faster For loop iteration and saving inside database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am looking for suggestion to make my for loop iterate faster. With about 2000 rows of data. Below code is taking lot of time to run. So far I have followed various Stack Overflow answers. For example reducing db queries and using Bulk insert to improve EF performance. It just improved marginally.

```
List<VehicleApplication> vehicleApplicationList = new List<VehicleApplication>();
List<ProductVehicleApplication> productVehicleApplicationList = new List<ProductVehicleApplication>();

if (inventoryjson["InventoryItems"][0]["VehicleApplications"] != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < inventoryjson["InventoryItems"][0]["VehicleApplications"].Count(); i++)
    {
        //database vehDb = new database();
        VehicleApplication vehicleApplication = new VehicleApplication();
        vehicleApplication.CategoryName = inventoryjson["InventoryItems"][0]["VehicleApplications"][i]["CategoryName"].ToString();
        vehicleApplication.MakeName = inventoryjson["InventoryItems"][0]["VehicleApplications"][i]["MakeName"].ToString();
        vehicleApplication.MfrLabel = inventoryjson["InventoryItems"][0]["VehicleApplications"][i]["MfrLabel"].ToString();
        vehicleApplication.ModelName = inventoryjson["InventoryItems"][0]["VehicleApplications"][i]["ModelName"].ToString();
        vehicleApplication.Note = inventoryjson["InventoryItems"][0]["VehicleApplications"][i]["Note"].ToString();
        vehicleApplication.PartTypeName = inventoryjson["InventoryItems"][0]["VehicleApplications"][i]["PartTypeName"].ToString();
        vehicleApplication.PositionName = inventoryjson["InventoryItems"][0]["VehicleApplications"][i]["PositionName"].ToString();
        vehicleApplication.Qty = inventoryjson["InventoryItems"][0]["VehicleApplications"][i]["Qty"].ToString();
        vehicleApplication.SubCategoryName = inventoryjson["InventoryItems"][0]["VehicleApplications"][i]["SubCategoryName"].ToString();
        vehicleApplication.YearID = inventoryjson["InventoryItems"][0]["VehicleApplications"][i]["YearID"].ToString();

        var existingVehicleApplication = dbVehiclesList.Where(x => x.MakeName == vehicleApplication.MakeName && x.ModelName == vehicleApplication.ModelName
            && x.CategoryName == vehicleApplication.CategoryName
            && x.MfrLabel == vehicleApplication.MfrLabel
            && x.PartTypeName == vehicleApplication.PartTypeName
            && x.PositionName == vehicleApplication.PositionName
            && x.Qty == vehicleApplication.Qty
            && x.YearID == vehicleApplication.YearID
            && x.SubCategoryName == vehicleApplication.SubCategoryName
            ).SingleOrDefault();

        if (existingVehicleApplication == null && vehicleApplicationList.Any(x => x.MakeName == vehicleApplication.MakeName && x.ModelName == vehicleApplication.ModelName && x.CategoryName == vehicleApplication.CategoryName && x.MfrLabel == vehicleApplication.MfrLabel && x.PartTypeName == vehicleApplication.PartTypeName && x.PositionName == vehicleApplication.PositionName && x.Qty == vehicleApplication.Qty && x.YearID == vehicleApplication.YearID && x.SubCategoryName == vehicleApplication.SubCategoryName) == false)
        {
            vehicleApplicationList.Add(vehicleApplication);
        }
        else
        {
            vehicleApplication = dbObj.VehicleApplication.SingleOrDefault(
            x => x.MakeName == vehicleApplication.MakeName
            && x.ModelName == vehicleApplication.ModelName
            && x.CategoryName == vehicleApplication.CategoryName
            && x.MfrLabel == vehicleApplication.MfrLabel
            && x.PartTypeName == vehicleApplication.PartTypeName
            && x.PositionName == vehicleApplication.PositionName
            && x.Qty == vehicleApplication.Qty
            && x.SubCategoryName == vehicleApplication.SubCategoryName
            && x.YearID == vehicleApplication.YearID);
        }

        ProductVehicleApplication productVehicleApplication = new ProductVehicleApplication();
        productVehicleApplication.Product = dbObj.Product.Single(x => x.Id == product.Id);
        productVehicleApplication.VehicleApplication = vehicleApplication;
        productVehicleApplicationList.Add(productVehicleApplication);
    }
}

dbObj.BulkInsert(productVehicleApplicationList);
dbObj.BulkInsert(vehicleApplicationList);
dbObj.SaveChanges();
```

UPDATE::1
From comments I have tried following. But it is still slow.

```
HashSet<VehicleApplication> vehicleApplicationList = new HashSet<VehicleApplication>();
                List<ProductVehicleApplication> productVehicleApplicationList = new List<ProductVehicleApplication>();
                if (jsonProduct["VehicleApplications"] != null)
                {
                 for (int i = 0; i < jsonProduct["VehicleApplications"].Count(); i++){
                            var vehicleApp = jsonProduct["VehicleApplications"][i];

                            VehicleApplication vehicleApplication = new VehicleApplication();
                            vehicleApplication.CategoryName = vehicleApp["CategoryName"].ToString();
                            vehicleApplication.MakeName = vehicleApp["MakeName"].ToString();
                            vehicleApplication.MfrLabel = vehicleApp["MfrLabel"].ToString();
                            vehicleApplication.ModelName = vehicleApp["ModelName"].ToString();
                            vehicleApplication.Note = vehicleApp["Note"].ToString();
                            vehicleApplication.PartTypeName = vehicleApp["PartTypeName"].ToString();
                            vehicleApplication.PositionName = vehicleApp["PositionName"].ToString();
                            vehicleApplication.Qty = vehicleApp["Qty"].ToString();
                            vehicleApplication.SubCategoryName = vehicleApp["SubCategoryName"].ToString();
                            vehicleApplication.YearID = vehicleApp["YearID"].ToString();


                            var existingVehicleApplication = dbVehiclesList.Where(x => x.MakeName == vehicleApplication.MakeName && x.ModelName == vehicleApplication.ModelName 
                                && x.CategoryName == vehicleApplication.CategoryName
                                && x.MfrLabel == vehicleApplication.MfrLabel
                                && x.PartTypeName == vehicleApplication.PartTypeName
                                && x.PositionName == vehicleApplication.PositionName
                                && x.Qty == vehicleApplication.Qty
                                && x.YearID == vehicleApplication.YearID
                                && x.SubCategoryName == vehicleApplication.SubCategoryName
                                ).SingleOrDefault(); 
                                
                    

                            if (existingVehicleApplication == null && vehicleApplicationList.Any(x => x.MakeName == vehicleApplication.MakeName && x.ModelName == vehicleApplication.ModelName && x.CategoryName == vehicleApplication.CategoryName && x.MfrLabel == vehicleApplication.MfrLabel && x.PartTypeName == vehicleApplication.PartTypeName && x.PositionName == vehicleApplication.PositionName && x.Qty == vehicleApplication.Qty && x.YearID == vehicleApplication.YearID && x.SubCategoryName == vehicleApplication.SubCategoryName) == false)
                            {
                                vehicleApplicationList.Add(vehicleApplication);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                vehicleApplication = existingVehicleApplication;
                                //vehicleApplication = dbVehiclesList.SingleOrDefault(
                                //x => x.MakeName == vehicleApplication.MakeName
                                //&& x.ModelName == vehicleApplication.ModelName
                                //&& x.CategoryName == vehicleApplication.CategoryName
                                //&& x.MfrLabel == vehicleApplication.MfrLabel
                                //&& x.PartTypeName == vehicleApplication.PartTypeName
                                //&& x.PositionName == vehicleApplication.PositionName
                                //&& x.Qty == vehicleApplication.Qty
                                //&& x.SubCategoryName == vehicleApplication.SubCategoryName
                                //&& x.YearID == vehicleApplication.YearID);

                            }

                            ProductVehicleApplication productVehicleApplication = new ProductVehicleApplication();
                            productVehicleApplication.Product = dbProductList.Single(x=>x.Id==product.Id);
                            productVehicleApplication.VehicleApplication = vehicleApplication;


                            productVehicleApplicationList.Add(productVehicleApplication);
                        }
                    }

                    dbObj.BulkInsert(productVehicleApplicationList);
                    dbObj.BulkInsert(vehicleApplicationList);
                    dbObj.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: `I am looking for suggestion to make my for loop iterate faster` would be more suitable over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). On a quick glance you could assign `inventoryjson["InventoryItems"][0]["VehicleApplications"][i]` to something local and get what you need from it...

Comment: I would run SQL profiler and examine each call to see where (if any) a bottleneck is occurring. For example, in your Where clause, perhaps an index would speed up the query?

Comment: `BulkInsert` - what is this method, from which library?

Comment: When you found an existing application,  you seem to read it again. Why?

Comment: `dbVehiclesList.Where(...` is probably slow, maybe looking at putting into a Dictionary or HashSet

Comment: `dbObj.VehicleApplication.SingleOrDefault`, `dbObj.Product.Single` - multiple access to the database is the reason for the slow work.

Comment: THanks for valuable comments guys::
So  @AlexanderPetrov BulkInsert is a faster way to insert than using add range thus saving time.

Charlieface Ok I will try your valuable insights. 
HansKeﬆing Somehow when I do save it is saving new one. Which makes me wonder why so I read it again. OK will try to replace that as well.

OK i will try to remove those calls and see what happens

Comment: Entity Framework does not have such a method. But there are many [Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/), some have the ability to Bulk Insert. Which library exactly did you get this method from?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework6.BulkInsert/  This one but that is not the cause of issue

Comment: I tried everything it is still slow :(

Comment: What is `jsonProduct["VehicleApplications"]`? It appears to be some kind of enumerable. If you can get the `Count()` once, rather than every iteration, that's probably good. Or, just do `foreach (var vehicleApp in jsonProduct["VehicleApplications"])` since it's not clear you need the index. It's not going to speed up anything, but you can move the lambda into `SingleOrDefault` and lose the `Where`. I would probably check for an existing vehicleApplication before creating a new one. But really, this belongs on [codereview.se] if it works as is.